# Generate letter in capital letter

Tags: excel, vba

Generate first and last letter In Capital in visual basic with excel

I want To Create Password In Excel with Vb CODE 
First letter Capital and Last letter capital 
Example  : A245F

```
Public Sub CmdCreatePassword_Click()
     Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
     For i = 1 To 70
          j = Int(Rnd(99) * 100)
          k = Int(Rnd(9))
          Cells(i, "a") = Chr(97 + Int(Rnd(26) * 26)) & IIf(j < 10, j + 27, j) & IIf(k < 9, k + 9, k) & Chr(122 - Int(Rnd(26) * 26))
     Next i
End Sub
Private Sub CmdCreatePassword_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As 
 MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    CmdCreatePassword_Click
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please review the StackOverflow help section, particularly on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Most importantly, make sure the question includes an actual question.  Also, when replying to a commenter to provide more information, do not add your reply as an answer.  Answers are intended for users to provide answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub CmdCreatePassword_Click()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 70
j = Int(Rnd(99) * 100)
k = Int(Rnd(9))
Cells(i, "a") = UCase(Chr(97 + Int(Rnd(26) * 26)) & IIf(j < 10, j + 27, j) & IIf(k < 9, k + 9, k) & Chr(122 - Int(Rnd(26) * 26)))
Next i
End Sub
```

Add Ucase function with the password that are getting generated. It will convert all characters to uppercase.

Hope it will useful for you!

Comment: Exactly ;), beaten me to it

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple formula instead?

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))&MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)&UPPER(RIGHT(A1, 1))
```

Produces the result as expected

[image]

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, if you don't particularly care about other potential characters becoming uppercase, or your data always follows the `alpha num num num alpha` format, you can just use this simplified formula instead:

```
=UPPER(A1)
```

Comment: @JvdV That was my original solution, but that would uppercase the entire string instead of first and last letter. I included extra lowercase characters for a reason in the 4th row

Comment: but in this specific case OP creates 3 numeric values, while only the 1st and 5th character of the password would be text. What's the added value of a formula?

Comment: @JvdV well I rather counted with the offchance, that there could be data that would not follow the format. If the data always follows `alpha num num num alpha` expression, then yeah, `=UPPER(A1)` would be sufficient as mentioned. No harm done really, it's not like you're losing any significant processing power by using my version of the formula and I always take the *better safe than sorry* approach to data handling

Comment: fair enough :). It sure was no offensive comment might it have looked that way. Just wondering why one would add a formula when in this specific case altering VBA with one word would do.

Comment: Don't worry, no offense was taken. In hindsight, I should have left my original solution as part of my answer as well, edited it back in now

Answer (score 0):

As you'll find from any [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/), character 'a' is 97 and 'z' is 122.  Also, 'A' is 65 and 'Z' is 90.  So, if you capital letters rather than lower case, replace your 97 and 122 values with 65 and 90, respectively.

I.e.:

```
Cells(i, "a") = Chr(65 + Int(Rnd(26) * 26)) & IIf(j < 10, j + 27, j) & IIf(k < 9, k + 9, k) & Chr(90 - Int(Rnd(26) * 26))
```

Answer (score 0):

replace 6th line with below

```
Cells(i, "a") = Chr(65 + Int(Rnd(26) * 26)) & IIf(j < 10, j + 27, j) & IIf(k < 9, k + 9, k) & Chr(90 - Int(Rnd(26) * 26))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some frippery and a little lazy. It uses a regex pattern,`[a-z]`, to replace the lowercase with uppercase. It works in this instance as you only have at the start and end and you want to replace both. It is a little lazy as if the first and end letters were to match this still attempts a replacement.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CmdCreatePassword_Click()
     Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
     For i = 1 To 70
          j = Int(Rnd(99) * 100)
          k = Int(Rnd(9))
          Cells(i, "a") = UcaseString(Chr(97 + Int(Rnd(26) * 26)) & IIf(j < 10, j + 27, j) & IIf(k < 9, k + 9, k) & Chr(122 - Int(Rnd(26) * 26)), "[a-z]")
     Next i
End Sub

Public Function UcaseString(Text As String, Pattern As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean) As String
    Dim re As Object, matches As Object, i As Long
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        .Pattern = Pattern

        If .test(Text) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(Text)
            For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
                Text = Replace$(Text, matches(i), UCase$(matches(i)))
            Next i
            UcaseString = Text
        Else
            UcaseString = Text
        End If
    End With   
End Function
```